# Why can I not deduce if the static member function exists

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have the following code:

```
#include <utility>

template<class T,class E = void>
struct func_impl;

template<class T,class E = void>
constexpr inline bool has_func = false;

template<class T>
constexpr inline bool has_func<T,decltype(func_impl<T>::apply(std::declval<T>()))> = true;

template<>
struct func_impl<int>
{
   static int apply(int i);
};

static_assert(has_func<int>);
```

The static_assert fails, where I expected it to succeed. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the default value of the 2nd template parameter `E` comes from the primary template, it's `void` and doesn't match the template parameter specialized in the specialization; which is specialized as `decltype(func_impl<T>::apply(std::declval<T>()))` (i.e. `int` in this case). Then the primary template but not specializatioin will be selected.

You could use [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t).

```
template<class T>
constexpr inline bool has_func<T, std::void_t<decltype(func_impl<T>::apply(std::declval<T>()))>> = true;
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^                                                 ^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5wocuStG5E8CKmiI)

Comment: Thank you! I am even beginning to grasp why my specialization was not chosen.